# How do I set up a database on PhpStorm?

Tags: php, mysql, database, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am in the process of setting up my development environment and I just need to set up the MySQL Database. I have a .sql file and I'd like to import the information from that into a local database in PhpStorm.

I have the .sql file in my main project folder and I dragged it over to the Database Tool Window and it showed up as a DDL.

My question is: How do I turn that into an actual database that I can run off of localhost?

**This is what I see**

[image]

Comment: Please visit [ https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Databases+and+SQL+Editor+in+PhpStorm#DatabasesandSQLEditorinPhpStorm-Settingupadatabaseconnection ]

Comment: ... as well as https://www.mysql.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no database in PhpStorm. You need to set up a local server and THEN connect PhpStorm to that database.

If you are a beginner on Windows then you cannot go wrong with [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html/).

PhpStorm can read the DDL but cannot store any data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: A better alternative to XAMPP is [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) if you plan to deploy to a *nix server.

Comment: I looked as Vagrant when I looked at Laravel but was too  clever for me. I think Kash is pretty new to the game. Is Vagrant the right steer for a newb? Genuine question and should I revisit it? I am pretty happy with XAMPP. I am still pretty much a newb myself.

Comment: Definitely re-visit it. It allows you to fire up a Virtual Machine with specific settings so that you can mirror your production server. Laravel have released [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) which is a pre-packaged configuration to apply the virtual machine.

Comment: I now see you have to buy VMware Vagrant plug-in for $75 (I don't think you had to back then) and on a Windoze machine you may have to change BIOS settings (I did when I looked at Vagrant ages ago) so I stand by my support of Xampp for us beginners.